# Spring Session in Clustered Environment

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

We have two apps that are shared sessions by the "Spring Session" between them.
In apps, there is a Form that Admin can force logout other online users. before we use "Spring Session", we get all online user from `SessionRegistry` and use below method for force logout user. but now when a user login to app1, `SessionRegistry` of app1 hold session Info but `SessionRegistry` of app2 not hold!

[image]

```
public void forceLogOut(int userId) {
    for (Object username : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
        User temp = (User) username;
        if (temp.getId().equals(userId)) {
            for (SessionInformation session : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(username, false)) {
                sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(session.getSessionId()).expireNow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have two questions:

1. when a user logged in from app1, app2 can not get all online user! how can I get all online users (same result) from tow app?
2. above method is not working, when I force logout one user from app2, that logged in from app1. what is the best way?

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same issue... You have to use a shared Session Registry, you are using an in memory one which is Map based. You aren't using the correct one so 1 and 2 in your current setup/config will never be possible.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
how can i store "SessionRegistry" in database? or how can i config this?
what is the best keywords for search this problem?

Comment: You already store all the information in Redis, you need a `SessionRegistry` implementation that reads this. Currently there is no support from the framework (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/65 for more information).

Comment: @M.Deinum please (see https://github.com/tomekkup/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-redis/src/main/java/com/kuprowski/redis/security/core/session/RedisSessionRegistry.java). is it good solution? use `RedisSessionRegistry` instead of `SessionRegistryImpl`.!

Comment: I'm not going to comment on that, but that is basically a `SessionRegistry` implementation for Redis. Something like that is what you should have.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks alot